# Gnome tweaks 42 removes duplicate settings

Tags: linux, themes, gnome

## Gnome 42 just removed duplicate settings from it which included the Applications theme.
42.beta

Beta release.

GNOME Tweaks 42 focuses on removing tweaks which are now duplicated by
Settings. Additionally, Tweaks 42 marks the GTK theme tweak as "Legacy".
In GNOME 42, the "Legacy Applications" setting will only apply to some
GTK3 apps and a limited set of GTK4 apps. Most core GNOME apps will
instead respect the user's dark and light mode preference via libadwaita.
Users interested in theming can continue to do so using more advanced
options such as the GTK_THEME environment variable

This is from the tweak tools github repo, now that applications is gone i cant change themes for my non legacy gnome applications. How can i apply themes for that, Someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Appearance > Style

Now all the updated gnome apps will respect theming from settings and things that are still using gtk3 will use the setting in tweaks